# Callback function for this.props.dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am calling a dispatch function as below

```
this.props
      .dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_REQUESTED,
        payload: {
          username,
          password,
        },
})
```

i want to dispatch another action on successfully execution of this action
i tried with `then` function but getting error that `this.props.dispatch(...).then is not a function`

Comment: Dispatching an action is asynchronous. So if you want another dispatch after this dispatch.

Comment: What is the context you want to use this in?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo on login success i want to call another API

Comment: @paruchuri-p yes iwant to another dispatch after this dispatch. how i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using redux saga, you can have a generator to watch for `LOGIN_SUCCESS`.

Dispatch this action after the API had successfully responded.

```
takeLatest(LOGIN_REQUESTED, watchForLogin)
takeLatest(LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, watchForLoginSuccess)

watchForLogin(action) {
  doLogin('/some/url')
    .then(response => dispatch(loginSuccess(response))) // dispatch login success
    .catch(error => dispatch(loginFailed(error))) // dispatch error
}

watchForLoginSuccess(action) {
  doSomethingAfterLogin()
}
```

Comment: i dont want this login in geneartors. can i do it in component itself?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use `redux-thunk` instead: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: @NIshamMahsin, think of middlewares - the behavioural aspect of a system that reacts once an action is dispatch. This way you separate responsibilities of rendering and behaviour.